# how to pass value dynamically to spring top function

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

Actually, I wanted to retrieve the Top 500 records in a table. I knew spring data has internal method findTop500 method for it. My question is can this 500 be passed dynamically? Suppose if my requirement changes to get Top1000 I don't want it to modify again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking about Spring data-methods

You can use a `Pageable` object to dynamically set how many entries you want to retrieve.
You can use it like this:

```
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, maxResults);
List<Record> records = repository.findAll(pageRequest);
List<Record> records = repository.findAllByKey(key, pageRequest);
```